# Removing files that do not exist

Tags: filesystems, files

I apologize for the possibly misleading title, but it is the best way I could think of to describe the problem, which is: I have several files that I can `cat`, but when I try to `rm` them I get a "No such file or directory" error.

```
$ cat "A11 D5 D5.txt"
... OUTPUT ...
$ rm -f "A11 D5 D5.txt"
rm: cannot remove `A11 D5 D5.txt': No such file or directory
```

I've tried overwriting the file and can execute the remove without error, but the file is still there; I can still cat the file.

```
$ echo "Boom" > "A11 D5 D5.txt"
$ cat "A11 D5 D5.txt"
Boom
$ rm -f "A11 D5 D5.txt"
$ cat "A11 D5 D5.txt"
Boom
$ rm -f "A11 D5 D5.txt"
rm: cannot remove `A11 D5 D5.txt': No such file or directory
```

I'm at a complete loss. I suspect a reboot would fix the problem, but I am really more interested in why such a thing would happen. Some sort of filesystem problem? (I don't have reboot privileges for the system; it's a university cluster.)

**Edit:** I get the following output

```
$ ls
A11 D5 D5.txt
$ ls -b
A11\ D5\ D5.txt
$ printf '<%q>\n'
<''>
```

I've also `stat`ed the file (just in case):

```
$ stat A11\ D5\ D5.txt 
  File: `A11 D5 D5.txt'
  Size: 5               Blocks: 8          IO Block: 131072 regular file
Device: 1bh/27d Inode: 18446744068941111933  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  596/  <username>)   Gid: ( 1015/<group>)
Access: 2012-12-09 22:48:29.000000000 -0600
Modify: 2012-12-09 22:56:44.835662498 -0600
Change: 2012-12-09 22:56:44.835662498 -0600
```

**Edit 2:** The filesystem is apparently of type "fuse" and

```
$ ls -lb A11\ D5\ D5.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 <username> <group> 5 Dec  9 22:56 A11\ D5\ D5.txt
```

Comment: what does `ls` show?

Comment: What is the output of `printf '<%q>\n' *`?

Comment: Specifically, look at `ls -b`

Comment: What does `df -T ./A11\ D5\ D5.txt | awk '{print $2}'` give. And `ls -lb ./A11\ D5\ D5.txt` ?

Comment: Does `find . -inum NNN -exec rm -i {} \;` work? Where `NNN` is inode number. That was a crazy big number tho. Over 18 quintillion inodes? Perhaps best to do a `find . -inum NNN -exec cat {} \;` first to be sure.

Comment: @Sukminder `find . -inum NNN -exec rm -i {} \;` does not work, same problem "No such file...". `find . -inum NNN -exec cat {} \;` successfully prints the file content. The system is a computing cluster, so I suspect the high rate of file creation has let to the crazy large number of inodes.

Comment: Why the file name in the error message is quoted by different "quotation mark"? The first one is [``[` (grave accent, backquote, backtick)]``](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent), the last one is [`' (apostrophe, single quotation mark)`](http://en.wikipedia.or/wiki/Apostrophe). Try `ls -l --quote-name` (or `ls -lQ` for short) to see if there're such quotation marks in your filename.

Comment: @LiuYan I ran your command and there are no quotation marks in the filename. I suspect that `ls -b` would have shown that if it did in fact have quotation marks. Further, if there were quotation marks (of some sort), would that not have mucked up the `cat` command as well?

Comment: This was truly weird. It show up as a normal file `0644` with no special characters. It is not a `.fuse_hiddenXXX` file. Show up on `ls`, is `cat` able etc. but not removable. Have had some problems with fuse and removal of files; but that is years ago. Do you manage to detect which fuse version is in use?

Comment: Does `lsof FileName` give any output?

Comment: @Sukminder The fuse version is `2.7.4`, and strangely `lsof` does not appear to be installed. I don't have install privileges.

Comment: I'm at a loss. Hopefully someone is able to read what can be done from all the information you have given. You could look at `strace` of rm - tho it is doubtful it will give you much. I.e. diff `strace rm SomeFileYouCanDelete` vs `strace rm StubbornFile`. Haven't messed with fuse for ages. Weird that `lsof` is not available. You might be able to compile and run it locally (no install). `wget` [Download](http://code.google.com/p/orisoft/downloads/detail?name=lsof.tar.gz&can=2&q=) unpack, `./Configure`, `make` and `./lsof`. (This worked on my restricted server).

Comment: If you have sufficient rights, I would try to remount the fuse fs. Do you know what kind of fuse fs actually is used? You can find it out e.g. by using `df .`.

Comment: It's definitely an oddity of this FUSE filesystem. A filesystem driver can make `rm` a no-op: it's technically possible, but normally not done that way. What filesystem is it?

Comment: What is output of `echo $?` immediately after `rm -f filename` ? That might help in some investigation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to using tools to determine the filename for you if you think it has some special characters you can't see.

```
ls | xargs -i rm -i {}
```

or

```
find . -exec rm -i {} \;
```